# How can I get a specific time of a date using SQL code

Tags: sql

How can I get a specific time of a date using SQL code?

Today is 02.05.2022 16:45:00 using ->

```
SELECT GETDATE()
```

What I need is 03.05.2022 8:00:00 -> ?

What would be the SQL code for it?

Thanks

**EDIT**

I can get the tomorrow's date using ->

```
SELECT DATEADD(day, 1, GETDATE())
```

but I actually need the date of tomorrow at 8 o'clock.

Comment: How are Today & what you want related?

Comment: What database are you using ?

Comment: are you trying to get time or date and time?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
SELECT DATEADD(HOUR, 8, CAST(CAST(GETDATE()+1 AS DATE) AS DATETIME))
```

Comment: This.  No messing around with strings, and keeping to native data and time data-types,

Answer (score 1):

> Today is 02.05.2022 16:45:00 using -> SELECT GETDATE() What i need is
> 03.05.2022 8:00:00 -> ?

Given your required date is "tomorrow" with no other narrative of requirements, the following is maybe what you are expecting:

```
select Convert(datetime,Convert(date,DateAdd(day,1,GetDate()))) + Convert(datetime, '08:00')
```

Comment: That was exactly what i was looking for. Tnx

Answer (score 0):

Try

```
SELECT CAST('2022-05-03 8:00:00' AS DATETIME) AS NewDate
```

Answer (score 0):

Assuming SQL Server, try this:

```
select convert(datetime,'03/05/2022 8:00:00')
```

Comment: Both the CAST and CONVERT examples work, CONVERT is a bit more lenient with date strings.